# Bott periodicity

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I studied (using Morse theory) Bott periodicity theorem for the unitary group $U(n)$: $\pi_{k}(U)=\pi_{k+2}(U)$. Do you know some interesting application of this result? Can this theorem help you to calculate homotopy groups of spheres?

Comment: The first application is the 2-periodicity of complex K-theory.  (It turns out that $\Omega U \simeq BU \times \mathbb{Z}$, which is the classifying space for even-dimensional $KU$-groups.)

Comment: If you are really, really interested in homotopy groups of spheres, the answer can be made to be "yes".  The fixed points of $KU$ along the conjugation map yield $KO$ (real K-theory, which is 8-periodic -- you can compute its homotopy groups, i.e. prove real Bott periodicity, from the homotopy groups of $KU$ using a homotopy fixed point spectral sequence).  This, in turn, relates to the (stable) homotopy groups of spheres via the J-homomorphism (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-homomorphism).

Comment: @AaronMazel-Gee Do you have some references for this?

Comment: Sure.  This all falls into the field of *stable homotopy theory*, in which the main objects of study are spectra: ordinary spaces give rise to spectra, and all extraordinary cohomology theories (such as $KU$ and $KO$) are repesented by spectra too.  So this would be the first thing to learn about, if you're not already familiar with it.  I can give some references if you like, but you should know that this is a long (but extremely beautiful!) road.

Comment: Also, here is a cool paper which I remember being called "8 views on Bott periodicity" that you might enjoy (although this is not the actual title) by Hohnhold, Stolz, and Teichner: http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/teichner/Papers/Bott-EFT.pdf .  You might need to know a small bit about spectra to read it, bu they're definitely not the main thrust.  There are really tons of directions you can go using Bott periodicity as a springboard.

Comment: For instance, the field of *chromatic homotopy theory* organizes the entire category of topological spaces in an extremely deep and satisfying way using cohomology theories that all satisfy a "generalized Bott periodicity".  In a sense, the category decomposes into a bunch of pieces, where there's one piece for every pair $(p,n)$ of a prime number $p$ and an $n \in [1,\infty]$, and then there's a single piece "at all primes" corresponding to $n=0$.  (You can see a picture on the first page of these notes: http://math.berkeley.edu/~aaron/writing/tmf-seminar-talk.pdf)

Comment: On a more serious note, you should check out the very nice (although somewhat unpolished) "Vector fields on spheres" notes (http://math.berkeley.edu/~ericp/latex/haynes-notes/haynes-notes.pdf) based on a course taught by Haynes Miller.  They use K-theory to prove the Hopf invariant 1 theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_invariant); from here one can rather easily deduce the vector fields on spheres theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_fields_on_spheres), which is a vast generalization of the hairy ball theorem.

Comment: More classically, a first application was in solving the parallelizability of spheres problem (this was done independently by Kervaire and, I think, Milnor). It also not only showed that K-theory had periodicity, it showed that K-theory exists! In other words- that it is a cohomology theory to begin with (how else does one know that BU is an infinite loop space?) Of course, all the other stuff Aaron mentioned is very cool too :)

Comment: Yup!  This is addressed in the notes on Miller's course I linked above.

Comment: @AaronMazel-Gee I read something about your posts. I am really interested about your second post: what is $KU$ and $KO$? How can I find a good introduction text in $K-$theory and stable homotopy? Can I find a direct relationship among real Bott periodicity and J-homomorphism?

Comment: @ArthurStuart: I think that Switzer's "Homotopy and Homology" is a great place to learn about stable homotopy theory, although I'm not sure whether one could call it "introductory".  If you've spent a bit of time with e.g. Hatcher (just so you have a feel for things, not because he really touches the stable world at all) then you should be good to go.  As for your question: Yes, absolutely!  The *stable* J-homomorphism is $\pi_n(SO) \rightarrow \pi_n^{\rm st}(S^0)$, and the source is given by nothing more or less than real Bott periodicity.

Comment: Chapter 3 of Adams's "blue book" (actually called "Stable homotopy and generalised homology", I think) is also a popular starting point.  I really love his writing.  This is much more conversational, and will ease you into things gently.

Comment: Two last comments.  (a) The first two chapters of Adams's blue book come logically *after* the third.  (b) In either of those references, you should definitely, definitely, definitely avoid the section on the smash product of spectra.  This issue was unresolved for decades, and in fact there's a theorem saying that no category of spectra can satisfy all 5 of a list of quite reasonable axioms.  There are by now many candidate workarounds, but you should just take it as a given that a "good" smash product exists and sidestep the whole mess.

Comment: @AaronMazel-Gee And for $K$-theory?

Comment: @ArthurStuart: Sorry, what are you asking?  If you're asking for a reference for K-theory, then I guess I should've said that (this perspective on) K-theory is part and parcel of stable homotopy theory, and is certainly covered in e.g. Switzer (although come to think of it you should probably skip his proof of Bott periodicity too -- you'll see immediately how your version implies the periodicity of the associated extraordinary cohomology theory).  If you mean to ask how $KU$ is related to the J-homomorphism, the answer is "via $KO$".

Comment: Perhaps I should at least say where the stable J-homomorphism comes from.  It's basically just given by $SO = \mbox{colim}_nSO(n) \rightarrow \mbox{colim}_n\Omega^nS^n = QS^0$.  This last space $QS^0$ essentially by definition has homotopy groups the stable homotopy groups of spheres (at any basepoint); this is just because $\pi_k(\mbox{colim}_n\Omega^n S^n) = \mbox{colim}_n \pi_k(\Omega^n S^n) = \mbox{colim}_n \pi_{n+k}(S^n) =: \pi_k^{\rm st}$.  (You can pass the $\pi_k$ through the colimit since $S^k$ is a finite complex, i.e. by the "small object argument".)

Comment: Jeez, how could I forget -- Hatcher also has an unfinished book project called "Vector bundles and K-theory" (abbreviated as VBKT in his other books) that you might want to check out.